# Cargo panics with FromBytesWithNulError when using bindgen with C++

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-bindgen

Solved! People seem to agree on it being a bug that's fixed, just not in the current version.

---

Am currently learning Rust, cause it's the hot shit and will dethrone C++, bluh, bluh, and came across bindgen, which seems obviously important when interfacing with C/C++ APIs.
Doing pretty much what the Rust Doc says when writing `build.rs` to invoke bindgen and it does work with C headers.
But when I try to use C++ headers, about which the Doc just tells me to use a .hpp header or add clang arguments to force C++, it panics with FromBytesWithNulError somewhere in the code generation.

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=wrapper.hpp");

    let bindings = bindgen::Builder::default().header("src/wrapper.hpp").generate()
        .expect("Can't generate bindings");

    let out_path = std::path::PathBuf::from(std::env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap());
    bindings.write_to_file(out_path.join("bindings.rs"))
        .expect("Can't write bindings to file");
}
```

stderr is

```
--- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: FromBytesWithNulError { kind: InteriorNul(1) }', C:\Users\tidem\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\bindgen-0.66.1\codegen\mod.rs:717:71
  stack backtrace:
     0: rust_begin_unwind
               at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library\std\src/panicking.rs:579:5
     1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
               at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library\core\src/panicking.rs:64:14
     2: core::result::unwrap_failed
               at /rustc/84c898d65adf2f39a5a98507f1fe0ce10a2b8dbc/library\core\src/result.rs:1750:5
     3: core::result::Result<T,E>::unwrap
     4: <bindgen::ir::var::Var as bindgen::codegen::CodeGenerator>::codegen
     5: <bindgen::ir::item::Item as bindgen::codegen::CodeGenerator>::codegen
     6: <bindgen::ir::module::Module as bindgen::codegen::CodeGenerator>::codegen::{{closure}}
     7: <bindgen::ir::module::Module as bindgen::codegen::CodeGenerator>::codegen
     8: <bindgen::ir::item::Item as bindgen::codegen::CodeGenerator>::codegen
     9: bindgen::codegen::codegen::{{closure}}
    10: bindgen::ir::context::BindgenContext::gen
    11: bindgen::codegen::codegen
    12: bindgen::Bindings::generate
    13: bindgen::Builder::generate
    14: build_script_build::main
    15: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
```

Seems like it doesn't even reach my `expect` so no idea where to even start.
Could be an obvious error, but literally started learning the language a few hours ago, so no clue.

I saw a GitHub Issue on the matter, but it was resolved and I'm on the newest version.

I tried telling cargo both `wrapper.hpp` and `src/wrapper.hpp`, neither of which worked, with the former (i think) working in C.

Also tried telling clang to force C++ with a `.h` file with seemingly no success.

Debug breaking `build.rs` doesn't seem to be a thing either, but the Stacktrace tells me it's a problem that's not for me to `expect` so whatever, but if someone wants to tell me how, that'd be great.

Comment: A panic within a library (and not from your `.expect()`) is usually seen as a bug and you should probably report it to the authors.

Comment: Actually I looked at it again, and [the issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-bindgen/issues/2566) you mentioned should solve this, but it hasn't been released yet.

Comment: ah alright, they marked it as solved so i assumed it was already in the current version but that makes sense